# I easy_install'ed Mercurial, and now I get "No script named 'hg'"

Tags: mercurial, easy-install, ubuntu-9.10

I installed Mercurial on (32-bit) Ubuntu 9.10, using:

```
sudo easy_install mercurial
```

It installed Mercurial 1.7.5.

I have since learned that using this way of installing is [denounced](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download) by the Mercurial Team, although the reasons why it shouldn't work are not clear.

When I ran the command `hg` it responded:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('mercurial==1.7.5', 'hg')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 448, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1160, in run_script
    raise ResolutionError("No script named %r" % script_name)
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: No script named 'hg'
```

How do I fix this? How do I easy_*un*install it?

Note: I have noticed `sudo hg` works.

Comment: 1,000 views. Zero votes! Is this question wasting people's time? Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages (or the appropriate directory for your Python install).

Type `ls -l`  and you will find an entry something like so.

```
drwx--S--- 5 root staff 4096 Feb 14 11:13 mercurial-1.7.5-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
```

You don't have access to that if you are not logged in as root. Try:

```
sudo chmod -R o+rX mercurial-1.7.5-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/
```

That gives you access and was enough to get things going again for me.

I still don't know how to uninstall the original mess that was made.

Comment: YOu should make that `o+rX` (capital X) because you want to add execute perms for all directories but not for all files.

Comment: Nice tip, @Ry4an, I didn't know you could do that. Updated.