# Uninstall Mercurial while install with easy_install?

Tags: python

i using **easy_install mercurial** to install Mercurial while i find my project needs a lower version of Mercurial.
so i want to uninstall it, however i cant do it.

typing **hg --version** i got:

> Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.1.2)
>   (see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)
>
> Copyright (C) 2005-2014 Matt Mackall and others
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

and typing **easy_install -m mercurial** i got:

> Searching for mercurial
>   Best match: mercurial 3.1.2
>   Processing mercurial-3.1.2-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg
>   Installing hg script to /usr/local/bin
>
> Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial-3.1.2-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg
>
> Because this distribution was installed --multi-version, before you can
>   import modules from this package in an application, you will need to
>   'import pkg_resources' and then use a 'require()' call similar to one of
>   these examples, in order to select the desired version:
>
> ```
> pkg_resources.require("mercurial")  # latest installed version
> pkg_resources.require("mercurial==3.1.2")  # this exact version
> pkg_resources.require("mercurial>=3.1.2")  # this version or higher
> ```
>
> Processing dependencies for mercurial
>   Finished processing dependencies for mercurial

but with **easy_install -m mercurial==3.1.2** or **easy_install -m mercurial>=3.1.2** can't work, i still got my hg command.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey Alen, was you able to solve this issue somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in terminal: 
`easy_install -m mercurial`

 and also make sure to check  [easy_install](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html) for more information.

Comment: i run this command and show my results on the description, any more idea? thx.

Comment: @AlenLiang perhaps try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991910/i-easy-installed-mercurial-and-now-i-get-no-script-named-hg